# Linux kernel shows "WARNING: at arch/x86/mm/pageattr.c:962 change_page_attr_set_clr" without explanation

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, kernel-module

I'm writing a x86_64 kernel module targeting Linux v3-v4 which uses [`set_memory_rw()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.108/source/arch/x86/include/asm/cacheflush.h#L104) on an address of a kernel symbol. While the call works I'm getting a warning without any explanation:

```
[  596.183643] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  596.183667] WARNING: at arch/x86/mm/pageattr.c:962 change_page_attr_set_clr+0x2ca/0x450()
```

Previously I was using a different method which called `virt_to_page()` and then [`set_pages_rw()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.108/source/arch/x86/include/asm/cacheflush.h#L141). However as the kernel source states this is a deprecated API and it recommends using `set_memory_rw()` instead

> These APIs should be considered *deprecated* and are likely going to
> be removed in the future.
> [...]
> Specifically, many users of the old APIs had a virtual address,
> called virt_to_page() or vmalloc_to_page() on that address to
> get a struct page* that the old API required.
> To convert these cases, use set_memory_*() on the original
> virtual address, do not use these functions.

**Can anyone explain what is the problem here?**
I think I'm tripping [this check](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.108/source/arch/x86/mm/pageattr.c#L941), which suggests I can just add `*addr &= PAGE_MASK;` but I don't want to do it blindly.

Comment: "I'm getting a warning without any explanation" - Explanations could be in the code the warning message refers to. In you case, it is `arch/x86/mm/pageattr.c:962` line which you need to check. Even if there is no explanations, the line should contain a failed check, which could give you a hint what is going wrong. Note, that a line of code is specific to your Linux kernel version and patches. E.g. version 3.10.108 doesn't contain a warning at given line: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.108/source/arch/x86/mm/pageattr.c#L962

Comment: @Tsyvarev in my case line 962 is equal to the standard 941: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.108/source/arch/x86/mm/pageattr.c#L941 - while I see the check I don't clearly understand where is the problem... does it force the address to point to the beginning of the page?

Comment: "does it force the address to point to the beginning of the page?" - Yes, it needs the address to be page-aligned. Whatever architecture you use (x86, arm, etc.), it cannot set a *particular* address to be writable or readable. The minimum unit of memory writability or readability is a **page**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think I'm tripping this check, which suggests I can just add *addr &= PAGE_MASK; but I don't want to do it blindly.

Sounds good to me (it's extremely likely that it is an "address not aligned to page boundary" problem; and it's extremely likely that not wanting to do it blindly is a good idea).

The likely case is that you have a range of addresses that you care about (and not a range of pages); and that is how you ended up with this problem. This implies:

a) You'll have be careful when calculating `numpages` (e.g. the original range could be like "4 bytes, with 2 bytes at the end of one page and 2 bytes at the start of the next page"). The right way is to round the "starting address" down (`pg = start_address & PAGE_MASK;`), round the "ending address" up (`end_page = ((start_address + size_in_bytes - 1) | ~PAGE_MASK) + 1;`), then calculate the number of pages (`numpages = end_page - pg`).

b) There may be other things in the same page/s that you do not want using the new page attributes. If that is the case then you've got a fundamental design problem.

Comment: Thank you! That was an excellent explanation. Now I know where's the issue and how to fix that - while I didn't find any instances of functions crossing the page boundary in my case it can definitely happen.